# zabbix 3.4 проблема с mysql

Tags: mysql, zabbix

Случилась проблема с zabbix 3.4 после перезагрузки не стартует mysql
ругается на память

```
2018-08-09T07:12:30.997068Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-08-09T07:12:30.997095Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2018-08-09T07:12:30.997100Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-08-09T07:12:30.997342Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-08-09T07:12:30.997445Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-08-09T07:12:30.998868Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-08-09T07:12:31.007572Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-08-09T07:12:31.009612Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2018-08-09T07:12:31.021430Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-08-09T07:12:31.061760Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2018-08-09T07:12:31.061804Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2018-08-09T07:12:31.066393Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: 1048576 bytes should have been written. Only 167936 bytes written. Retrying for the remaining bytes.
2018-08-09T07:12:31.066408Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Retry attempts for writing partial data failed.
2018-08-09T07:12:31.066415Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Write to file ./ibtmp1failed at offset 8388608, 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 167936 were written. Operating system error number 28. Check that your OS and file system support
2018-08-09T07:12:31.066423Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'
2018-08-09T07:12:31.066427Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2018-08-09T07:12:31.066432Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not set the file size of './ibtmp1'. Probably out of disk space
2018-08-09T07:12:31.066437Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create the shared innodb_temporary
2018-08-09T07:12:31.066441Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2018-08-09T07:12:31.670310Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2018-08-09T07:12:31.670342Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-08-09T07:12:31.670352Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-08-09T07:12:31.670361Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2018-08-09T07:12:31.670367Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-08-09T07:12:31.670387Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-08-09T07:12:31.670975Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

2018-08-09T07:13:01.337520Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
2018-08-09T07:13:01.337574Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
2018-08-09T07:13:01.488132Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2018-08-09T07:13:01.488996Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.21-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 2546 ...
2018-08-09T07:13:01.492281Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2018-08-09T07:13:01.492301Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2018-08-09T07:13:01.492305Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2018-08-09T07:13:01.492309Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2018-08-09T07:13:01.492313Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2018-08-09T07:13:01.492317Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2018-08-09T07:13:01.492533Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2018-08-09T07:13:01.492629Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2018-08-09T07:13:01.493927Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2018-08-09T07:13:01.500904Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2018-08-09T07:13:01.502535Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2018-08-09T07:13:01.514107Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2018-08-09T07:13:01.577457Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2018-08-09T07:13:01.577501Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2018-08-09T07:13:01.582541Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: 1048576 bytes should have been written. Only 163840 bytes written. Retrying for the remaining bytes.
2018-08-09T07:13:01.582556Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Retry attempts for writing partial data failed.
2018-08-09T07:13:01.582564Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Write to file ./ibtmp1failed at offset 8388608, 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 163840 were written. Operating system error number 28. Check that your OS and file system support
2018-08-09T07:13:01.582572Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'
2018-08-09T07:13:01.582576Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
2018-08-09T07:13:01.582581Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not set the file size of './ibtmp1'. Probably out of disk space
2018-08-09T07:13:01.582585Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create the shared innodb_temporary
2018-08-09T07:13:01.582589Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2018-08-09T07:13:02.186220Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2018-08-09T07:13:02.186248Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2018-08-09T07:13:02.186257Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2018-08-09T07:13:02.186266Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2018-08-09T07:13:02.186272Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2018-08-09T07:13:02.186291Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2018-08-09T07:13:02.186723Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

df -h

```
root@zabbix:/home/appliance# df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                         2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        396M  5.6M  390M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/zabbix--vg-root  5.1G  4.8G  7.6M 100% /
tmpfs                        2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                        2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                    472M   61M  387M  14% /boot
```

Что можно сделать, как исправить?

Comment: *Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'* Почисти раздел, да... или смотри, что с квотами... или просто проверь файловую систему на ошибки.

Comment: Я не очень силён в linux. в /dev/mapper/ лежит файл zabbix--vg-root. Как почистить раздел?

Comment: Посмотреть вывод `vgs` есть ли ещё свободное место в томе и если есть, - расширить lvm-раздел, в противном случае... удалить чего-нить :)